# Alternate ending word in vim matchit pairs

Tags: plugin-matchit

I'm trying to get `%` to match custom keyword pairs

With vim matchit, I can do

```
let b:match_words=
            \ '\<Start\>:\<Stop\>'
```

to match `Start` and `Stop`.

I would like to match `Start` with either `Stop` or `Stop2`. How can I do this?

I have tried

```
let b:match_words=
            \ '\<Start\>:\<Stop\>,' .
            \ '\<Start\>:\<Stop2\>'
```

but then `%` only jumps from `Stop`/`Stop2` to `Start` but not from `Start` to `Stop2`.

I also have instances where I'd like where multiple possible start words should match with a single stop word (I don't think I have one where both the start and the stop have multiple spellings, if this matters.)

How can this kind of matching be done in vim?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The matchit plug-in takes regular expressions for its matches from `b:match_words`, so you can easily use a regular expression that matches both possible end keywords to accomplish that.

For your specific case:

```
let b:match_words= '\<Start\>:\<Stop2\?\>'
```

But assuming the end keywords a don't have any common parts, let's say `Stop` or `Finish`, then you can use:

```
let b:match_words= '\<Start\>:\<\(Stop\|Finish\)\>'
```

See [`:help b:match_words`](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/v8.2.0/runtime/pack/dist/opt/matchit/doc/matchit.txt#L244) for all the details on what is supported through that setting.

Comment: Thanks. Had tried `?`, but without the `\\`. Gotta get used to vim style regexes. :)

Comment: @PSkocik Same here! There's `\v` you can use to make them "very magic" but those can also take some getting used to... Glad this fixed it for you!